# Rscript Linux timestamp to ISO Date format

Tags: r

How can I take a Linux timestamp and convert it into the following string format?

```
Linux time = 1426644063000
ISO Date format = "2015-03-18T02:01:03.000Z"
```

strptime might be one option but is there a simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
x <- 1426644063000
format(as.POSIXct(x/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC"), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
output: "2015-03-18T02:01:03Z"
```